# Issue with Extension Code Coverage

Tags: apex, visualforce, unit-test, controller-extension

I have an Extension that works perfectly but the Test Class only has 65% code coverage. I cannot figure out why I don't have 100% (or at least 75%). Any help is greatly appreciated!

Extension Class

```
    public class timeCardExtension {

    Public User u {get;set;}

    public timeCardExtension(ApexPages.StandardController stdController){
      u = New User();
      u = [SELECT Id, Name, Clocked_In__c from User WHERE Id =:userinfo.getUserId()];
    }

    public PageReference clockIn(){
        try{
      List<Time_Card__c> tc = [SELECT Id, Date__c, Clock_In__c, Time_Left_for_Lunch__c, Time_Back_from_Lunch__c, Clock_Out__c, User__c from Time_Card__c Where Date__c = :system.date.today() AND User__c = :u.id Limit 1];
        if(tc.size() < 1){     
           Time_Card__c tcNew = new Time_Card__c();
            tcNew.Date__c = system.date.today();
            tcNew.User__c = u.Id;
            tcNew.Clock_In__c = system.now();
            tc.add(tcNew);

         database.insert(tc,true);

            u.Clocked_In__c = True;
            update u;
        }
        else if(tc.size() >0){
            for(Time_Card__c t : tc){
                if(t.Time_Left_for_Lunch__c == null){
                t.Time_Left_for_Lunch__c = system.now();
                update t;

                u.Clocked_In__c = False;
                update u;
                }
                else if(t.Time_Back_from_Lunch__c == null){
                t.Time_Back_from_Lunch__c = system.now();
                update t;

                u.Clocked_In__c = True;
                update u;
                }
                else if(t.Clock_Out__c == null){
                t.Clock_Out__c = system.now();
                update t;
                    u.Clocked_In__c = false;
                    update u;
                }
            }
        }
        }
        catch (System.DMLException ex){
            ApexPages.addMessages(ex);
        }
      PageReference pg = new PageReference(ApexPages.currentPage().getUrl());
        pg.setRedirect(true);
      return pg;
    }

}
```

Test Class

```
@isTest
public class timeCardExtensionTest {

    static testMethod void timeCardExtensionTest(){

        Profile p = [SELECT Id from Profile WHERE Name ='System Administrator'];

        User usr = new User();
        usr.FirstName = 'Cole';
        usr.LastName = 'Conroy';
        usr.Email = 'cconroy@sesaco.com';
        usr.Username = 'colecolecole@sesaco.com';
        usr.Alias = 'colec';
        usr.TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Chicago';
        usr.LocaleSidKey = 'en_US';
        usr.EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8';
        usr.LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US';
        usr.ProfileId = p.id;
        usr.Clocked_In__c = false;
        insert usr;

        Time_Card__c tc = new Time_Card__c();
            tc.date__c = system.today();
            tc.User__c = usr.id;
            tc.Clock_In__c = system.now();
            tc.Time_Left_for_Lunch__c = system.now();
            insert tc;

        ApexPages.standardController con = new ApexPages.standardController(tc);
        timeCardExtension ext = new timeCardExtension(con);

        Test.startTest();
        System.runAs(usr){
            ext.u = usr;
            try{
                ext.clockIn();
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                System.debug('error');
        }
        }
        Test.stopTest();
    }

}
```

VF Page

```
<apex:page standardController="Time_Card__c" extensions="timeCardExtension" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">

    <apex:form id="theForm">
        <apex:sectionHeader title="Clock In/Out" />
        <apex:PageMessages id="messages"/>
        <apex:PageBlock id="buttons">
            <apex:PageBlockButtons location="top">
                <apex:commandButton value="Clock In/Out" action="{!clockIn}" />
            </apex:PageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageblockSection rendered="{!IF($User.Clocked_In__c = True,True,False)}" columns="1" >
                <div style="background-color:green;border:1px solid #cdcdcd; padding:8px; width:90%; text-align:center;">
                    <h3 style="color:#fff;">
                        You Are Currently Clocked In
                    </h3>
                </div>
            </apex:pageblockSection>
            <apex:pageblockSection rendered="{!IF($User.Clocked_In__c = False,True,False)}" columns="1" >
                <div style="background-color:red;border:1px solid #cdcdcd; padding: 8px; width:90%; text-align:center;">
                    <h3 style="color:#fff;">
                        You Are Currently Clocked Out
                    </h3>
                </div>
            </apex:pageblockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
                <div style="text-align:center;">
                     <a href="/a53" target="_blank">View Time Cards</a>
                </div>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:PageBlock>         
    </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume you haven't covered tc.size() < 1 scenario.

Answer (score 3):

Use the following steps to see what code is being covered and what is not:

1. Open the Developer console
2. Run your test classes
3. Open the class you are trying to get coverage and you will see what sections of the code have coverage and what do not.

Once you have done this you should be able to understand what is not getting coverage and what is. If it is not entering an if statement then your test class is not meeting the criteria, if you are missing entire functions then they are not being called in your test process etc...